# How do you write "x is a set" in logic?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Suppose I want to express "x is a set" in logic, perhaps FOL.

For example, a predicate $S(x)$ which is $true$ if $x$ is a set and $false$ if $x$ is not a set.

How should this be written, formally?

Comment: You need to specify a domain of discourse and a signature for your first order language. In first order *set theory*, everything is a set, so no such predicate is needed.

Comment: Being a set is a semantic notion. You need to have some sort of intended interpretation of your first-order theory to make sense of such a claim. Otherwise, you may as well ask how to specify something is blue in first-order logic.

Comment: The first issue is: are you working in (some) *set theory*? Or are you working in "general" predicate logic? If the second, you have to use a language with a predicate symbol $S(x)$ and a binary *relation* symbol $E(x,y)$, where the fist one must be interpreted as "x is a Set" and the second one must be interpreted as "x is an Element of y". At this point, you have to add some axioms governing the two.

Comment: FWIW in my proof checking software, I have a unary Set predicate for "ordinary" sets, Set' for sets of ordered pairs, S'' for sets of ordered triples, and so on. There is no built-in definition of a set. These predicates are used only to indicate that the axioms of set theory are applicable to the object specified, e.g. Set(x) means that the axioms of set theory are applicable to x, e.g. there exists a power set of x.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the wikipedia page on the [NBG set theory axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory), using [Mendelson's modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#Classes_and_sets) of those axioms, one can take the predicate to be
$$S(x) := \exists c \, (x \in c)
$$

Comment: The set $c = \{\emptyset\}$ witnesses that $S(\emptyset)$ is true.

Comment: ∅∈{∅}. How is S(∅) false? I imagine, that you misread it to mean c∈x rather than x∈c

Comment: @MichaelCarey, you are absolutely right, I misread it. I am sorry.

Comment: Hang on, doesn't $S(x)$ mean "there exists a set which $x$ is a member of"? That doesn't say anything about whether $x$ is a set or not.

Comment: No, this is NBG set theory, the primitive objects are "classes". Every variable represents a class. So, if you like, you can read $S(x)$ in plain language as meaning "there exists a class which $x$ is a member of".

Comment: The comments to your post are apt here. I have made a convenient assumption for you when writing my answer: I have *assumed* a choice of domain of discourse and signature as suggested by Karl, and I have *assumed* a choice of set theory as suggested by MauroAllegranza.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Why not just define $S(x)$ as $S \in V$, where $V$ is the Von Neumann universal class?